# How can I set a new app as my default launcher on a Galaxy Ace?

Tags: launcher, samsung-galaxy-ace, default-applications

I downloaded a launcher app on my Samsung Galaxy Ace (iPhone Locker; actually its a locker app but it pretends to be a launcher). Now when I press the `Home` button, the list of launcher apps pops up. This list contains iPhone locker, and when I select that it is set, but the next time I click on `Home` the launcher list pops up again. I checked in my application settings and iPhone Locker's `Clear Default` button is grayed out, so it looks like it has not yet been made the default app. How can I make this my default launcher?

Comment: Usually there is a checkbox on the list of possible defaults that says something to the effect of "Make this the default app for this action". Do you see something like that? Are you checking that box?

Comment: yes i do check the checkbox below the list, it remains in effect for sometime and after that it again asks for the launcher app to select

Answer (score 1):

Go to menu > settings > applications > manage applications > *your current launcher* and tap `Clear data` button. Then, after pressing "home" button, a dialog should pop out, asking you, which application should be used to complete the task.

If this won't work try reinstalling the application. And do not move it to SD card ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Default App Manager Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appiator.defaultappmanager) or Pro. It can solve your problem.